# java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file moveFileToDirectory

Tags: java, fileutils

I'm trying to move the following files in the if statement by using FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory, after the files have been converted. JPG and gif files get moved to the new folder, but whenever the program finds an ICO file it won't move that file to the new folder and gives med the StackTrace: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'original path of the file' after copy to 'the new path for the file'.
Here is the code for the method:

```
public void storeOriginalImages() {
    for(File file: model.getFileList()) {
        if(file.getName().endsWith(".GIF") || file.getName().endsWith(".gif") || file.getName().endsWith(".JPG") 
                || file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")  || file.getName().endsWith(".ico") || file.getName().endsWith(".ICO")
                || file.getName().endsWith(".BMP") || file.getName().endsWith(".bmp")) {
            System.out.println("in copy else");
            File illegalExtension = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
            File illegalExtensionDest = new File(model.getTargetexcelFilepath() + "/" + model.getFolderName() + "_img_backup");
            System.out.println(illegalExtension + "/" + illegalExtensionDest);

            try {
                FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(illegalExtension, illegalExtensionDest, true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is how the ICO file is converted to png:

```
else if(s.getName().endsWith(".ico") || s.getName().endsWith(".ICO")) {
            List<BufferedImage> bi = ICODecoder.read(new File(s.getAbsolutePath()));
            System.out.println("reading");
            ImageIO.write(bi.get(0), "png", new File(s.getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile(), fileNameWithOutExt + ".png"));
            System.out.println("Ico was converted.");
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the ico file is not used by another process?

Comment: @Debmalya Biswas Before this method is called, the program converts jpg and gif to jpeg and ico files to png. The jpg and gif files are moved to the new folder but not the ico files.

Comment: I suspect that somehow programme can not release the ico resource. The method you shared look good to me. I think the isssue is in the conversion method

Comment: @DebmalyaBiswas I've been looking into that too and have seen another question similar to this one where the comments suggest to .close() the file, but it wont let me. I've also added the code for the conversion now.

Comment: Investigate the cause by leaving out the conversion. Just try to move the file without converting it. Do you still get an exception? If so, check the file permissions.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException it worked without converting the ICO file and I even went and got full control of the folder, and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Then it sounds like the conversion is keeping the file open. I can see from the source code of ICODecoder that it tries to close the file, and logs at FINE level if it can't. Log everything and see if ICODecoder leaves a log message saying it can't close the file.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException The file did not close, and I didnt find away around it to make it close. Luckily Debmalya Biswas hepled me with a solution. Thank you both for taking your time and helping me!

Comment: I can see what the problem is. Earlier versions of image4j didn't close the file. This was corrected in 2015. You should get the latest version of image4j. Then you won't have this problem.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Its working on my stationary computer where I wrote this code on, but did not want to work on my laptop or my classmates laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your example and edited a bit. It seems when ICODecoder try to read from file using the stream it did not close it properly so you need to close it in your code. Here is the working example

```
File oldFile = new File("a.ico");
try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(oldFile)) {
     List<BufferedImage> bi = ICODecoder.read(inputStream);
     ImageIO.write(bi.get(0), "png", new File("a" + ".png"));

} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Something happend", e);
}
FileUtils.moveFile(oldFile, new File("a.jpg"));
```

You need to close the input stream before moving the file.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and helping me out. This worked!